# ClickOnce deployment of .NET 4.0.3 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have installed the update for [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4.0.3 [into Visual Studio 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600214) and can now target framework 4.0.3, but it is not available as a prerequisite when I look at the options within ClickOnce.

How do I deploy this via ClickOnce?